# how to add in key:value into empy dict with values be more than 1 items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, user-interface, append

i need to take the user input from the text boxes and put it into my dict.
my code is this but i seem to get keyerror.,

```
my_Dict = {}
v = self._etyV.get() # vehicle number 
n = self._etyN.get() # time in 
in, out, charge = m_Dict
```

this is to append into my_Dict with v as the key and in as value.
but since time out and charge is not recorded yet it will just take as None.

```
my_Dict[v] = {in, None, None}
```

Comment: Can you specify the exact error? The question isn't explained well enough

Comment: `in` should /can not be used as variable name.

Comment: what is `m_dict` ? NameError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is

```
my_Dict.update({v : [time_in, None, None]})
```

Also for future reference the word `in` is a reserved keyword in python, not sure if you were aware.